# Convert Eb Platform To Solution Stack Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, ebcli

Is there any official way or 'the right way' to convert one of the platforms returned by `eb platform list` to the latest version of the eb solution stacks listed by `aws elasticbeanstalk list-available-solution-stacks --query 'SolutionStacks'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`eb platform list` is going to give you a list of platform "families." Essentially, they are modified names of platforms which have different versions. You probably can't use them "as-is" outside of the EB CLI but you can use them as a heuristic for querying the platform versions from the AWS CLI.

You can use the names from `eb platform list` as query filter for `list-platform-versions`. So, lets say you're looking for the latest Java 8 platform.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions --filters='[{"Type":"PlatformName","Operator":"begins_with","Values":["Java 8"]},{"Type":"PlatformVersion","Operator":"=","Values":["latest"]}]'
```

That will return one item which you can pluck the ARN and use that as an input into `describe-platform-version`.

```
aws elasticbeanstalk describe-platform-version --platform-arn 'arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.5.5'
```

That response should have the solution stack name for the latest platform.

Comment: can you modify your answer for scripted input? i.e. somewhere set `PLATFORM='multi-container-docker-17.03.2-ce-(generic)'` and process it to the input array you need so that it returns the latest solution stack string?

Comment: really just the appropriate filter part. getting the ARN is sufficient

Comment: You're gonna have some difficulty converting the string `"multi-container-docker-17.03.2-ce-(generic)"` into "Multi-container Docker". The way the EBCLI represents it's platform inputs is meant for command line input. So it does a transform on the platform name to make it "dasherized". You can't really use that directly with the Elastic Beanstalk service because it doesn't support fuzzy matching as far as I can tell.

Comment: I think you're going to be better off not using `eb platform list`. Instead, use `aws elasticbeanstalk list-platform-versions --filters='[{"Type":"PlatformVersion","Operator":"=","Values":["latest"]}]'`.

That is going to be 'the right way.'

Comment: Wish there were more up buttons for this answer. Thanks so much! I put the two steps together into https://gist.github.com/matschaffer/36977dd7ee07d514934fcbb95b25589f and now I never have to worry about finding the right latest stack solution name again!